# Parse.com PFLoginView UITextfield display issue. Cant remove border?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, uitextfield

I'm having some difficulty with overriding the parse.com elements in the PFLoginView.
Everything is fine except for the userName and password UITextfields.
I've got most of the 'stock' display removed, but I can't seem to get rid of the top and bottom bars of the field (see screenshot)

[image]

I've tried just about everything.

Heres my the code in my viewDidLayoutSubviews method.

```
[self.logInView.usernameField setBackground:nil];
[self.logInView.usernameField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.logInView.usernameField setPlaceholder:@""];
[self.logInView.usernameField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
```

I basically want the entire field blank, I'm using a uiimageview for the fields background you see in the screenshot with the icons. The icons and grey bars are mine, the white bars I have no idea how to remove.

Any tips would be great, I can't seem to get them removed.

Comment: Im thinking your going to have to create your own view... Just create a `PFLoginViewController` class and create the view of the controller the way you want... Then override the `PFLoginViewController` delegate methods to handle the login process

Comment: How are you adding the UIImageView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The login screen in the newest version of the Parse SDK is using a custom PFTextField subclass which is responsible for drawing the borders you see here. None of the usual UITextField methods for borders will change the style or make this go away.

To simply remove the border altogether you can set the separator style in your `viewDidLoad` method as follows:

```
[self.logInView.usernameField setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"separatorStyle"];
[self.logInView.passwordField setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"separatorStyle"];
```

Comment: This did the trick.
Don't think I would have stumbled across that by myself.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to change it is a layer in your viewDidLoad method:

```
CALayer *layer = self.logInView.usernameField.layer;
layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

or try

```
self.logInView.usernameField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
```